# Как сохранить повторяющиеся символы?

Tags: python, python-3.x, сортировка

В процессе изучения Python поставил себе задачу написания небольшого примитивного шифровальщика, который будет шифровать введенное слово, сопоставляя каждый символ с заданным в словаре значением, или расшифровывать в обратном порядке. В приведенном участке кода описано только мое видение процесса шифрования слова из переменной open_pass.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
# Использую данное упорядочивание, чтобы при выводе результата сопоставления не терялась последоваительнгость open_pass. 
# Читал, что dict умеет запоминать порядок вставки, но пока не смог разобраться.
open_pass = list('Password') # вдальнейшем будет так list(input('Enter open part of password: '))
secure = {'!Q':'a', '_>':'b', ':3':'c', 'N9':'d', '0.':'e', '=}':'f', '@#':'g', '](':'h', 'ay':'i', 'V*':'j',
          '$%':'k', '&j':'l', '+-':'m', 'k#':'n', '3,':'o', '[<':'p', '.,':'q', 'aP':'r', 'Bf':'s', 'I;':'t',
          'S6':'u', '_':'v', 'C;':'w', 'ns':'x', 'R|':'y', ')o':'z', '&z':'A', '%h':'B', '$)-':'C', 'B;':'D', 'lK':'E',
          'lJ':'F', '||':'G', 'ld':'H', '()':'I', '}{':'J', '+=_':'K', '__0':'L', '&^%':'M', '><?':'N', 'hsj':'O',
          '|][':'P', 'm<':'Q', 'klH':'R', '(!*':'S', 'mH':'T', 'ad':'U', 'kj':'V', ')as':'W', '/.L':'X', 'zdf':'Y',
          ']|p':'Z', 'zja':'1', 'okk':'2', '@34':'3', 'l}|':'4', 'xn':'5', 'zsf':'6', '89L':'7', '#4':'8', 'lL':'9',
          'Opk':'0'} # словарь в котором приводятся соответствия символов к шифруемым значениям
reversed_dict = {x: y for y, x in secure.items()} #реверс словаря для шифровки
result = OrderedDict()
for a in open_pass:
    result[a] = reversed_dict[a]
print(result)
```

В результате получаю:

```
OrderedDict([('P', '|]['), ('a', '!Q'), ('s', 'Bf'), ('w', 'C;'), ('o', '3,'), ('r', 'aP'), ('d', 'N9')])
```

Как видно в результате 's' выводится 1 раз, а в шифруемом пароле идет подряд 2 раза. Вопрос, как сделать, чтобы выводились все символы из шифруемого пароля при условии, что они повторяются?
Спасибо большое за уделенное время. Извините за глупые вопросы.

Comment: Шифрование прямым преобразованием да еще в неравноразмерные строки - не очень хорошая идея в принципе.

Comment: @strawdog, про прямое преобразование я понял, но это просто учебная задача поставленная самому себе. Я новичок (не яд, который никого не может нормально убить:-)) в этом деле. А вот про неравноразмерные строки не дошло. Вас не затруднит объяснить в 2-х словах или ткните носом, что гуглить?

Comment: Вы серьезно увеличиваете трудоемкость дешифровки, потому что зашифрованные строки содержат ограниченный набор символов, которые будут повторяться. например, в зашифрованной строке ваше дешифратор должен будет как-то определять, соответствие чему искать - "_" или "__0".

Comment: @РоманП. Ну, кстати, да, с расшифровкой `_` у вас будут проблемы, мой способ не справится, он не отличит от `_>` и `__0`, там нужно будет хитрее что-то придумывать.

Comment: @strawdog ))) я понял, о чем Вы писали, когда начал делать алгоритм дешифровки)))) Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Словарь - это всегда словарь. Что просто `dict`, что `OrderedDict` - это всё-равно словарь. А в словаре ключ не может повторяться.

Пишите результат в список (список - это упорядоченная структура, где элементы могут повторяться). Не совсем понимаю, что вы хотите на выходе, но вот максимально близко к вашему выводу и со всеми символами:

```
result = [(a, reversed_dict[a]) for a in open_pass]
print(result)
```

Вывод:

```
[('P', '|]['), ('a', '!Q'), ('s', 'Bf'), ('s', 'Bf'), ('w', 'C;'), ('o', '3,'), ('r', 'aP'), ('d', 'N9')]
```

Просто закодированная строка, без ключей словаря, а также раскодирование:

```
result = ''.join([reversed_dict[a] for a in open_pass])
print(result)

restore = ""
buff = ""
for ch in result:
    buff += ch
    if buff in secure:
        restore += secure[buff]
        buff = ""
print(restore)
```

Вывод:

```
|][!QBfBfC;3,aPN9
Password
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам. В конце концов хочу при вводе слова - его кодировать и раскодировать обратно.

Comment: @РоманП. Добавил кодирование и раскодирование

Comment: Спасибо, но я не буду пока читать))) сначала сам сделаю, потом сверюсь. Ну, или если не получится...)) /жму руку/